# Trying to insert the values of one Pandas Dataframe into another Dataframe using DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

can't figure this one out. I want to merge the values of one Dataframe into the other Dataframe, using DateTimeIndex, but I can't seem to make it work. Here are the (printed) dataframes:

```
                            open   high    low  close  volume  trade_count       vwap  minutes
timestamp                                                                                     
2022-04-11 04:00:00-04:00  17.95  18.13  17.89  17.95    7107          184  17.963452        0
2022-04-11 04:01:00-04:00  17.90  17.94  17.84  17.84    2978           71  17.895107        1
2022-04-11 04:02:00-04:00  17.90  17.94  17.66  17.70    4495           67  17.717039        2
2022-04-11 04:03:00-04:00  17.90  17.94  17.66  17.84    3795           58  17.764274        3
2022-04-11 04:04:00-04:00  17.90  17.94  17.66  17.80    3912           55  17.758436        4
...                          ...    ...    ...    ...     ...          ...        ...      ...
2022-04-11 19:55:00-04:00  18.37  18.44  18.30  18.34    7957           31  18.327004       55
2022-04-11 19:56:00-04:00  18.37  18.44  18.30  18.35    5361            6  18.340563       56
2022-04-11 19:57:00-04:00  18.37  18.44  18.30  18.36    1250           16  18.346664       57
2022-04-11 19:58:00-04:00  18.37  18.44  18.30  18.37    2524           30  18.366807       58
2022-04-11 19:59:00-04:00  18.37  18.44  18.30  18.43    3305           41  18.409014       59

[790 rows x 8 columns]
```

```
                            open   high    low  close  volume  trade_count       vwap
timestamp                                                                            
2022-04-08 04:00:00-04:00  19.69  19.88  19.69  19.82    8246          157  19.780987
2022-04-08 04:15:00-04:00  19.82  19.84  19.77  19.77    2995           73  19.804855
2022-04-08 04:30:00-04:00  19.80  19.80  19.77  19.80    2630           42  19.794878
2022-04-08 04:45:00-04:00  19.79  19.80  19.79  19.79    2294           23  19.793871
2022-04-08 05:00:00-04:00  19.80  19.81  19.80  19.81     888           15  19.805281
...                          ...    ...    ...    ...     ...          ...        ...
2022-04-11 18:45:00-04:00  18.40  18.42  18.31  18.34   21587          112  18.368550
2022-04-11 19:00:00-04:00  18.39  18.67  18.35  18.39   26144           72  18.388739
2022-04-11 19:15:00-04:00  18.39  18.39  18.30  18.35   46662          128  18.340306
2022-04-11 19:30:00-04:00  18.33  18.44  18.33  18.44   10784           61  18.351895
2022-04-11 19:45:00-04:00  18.42  18.43  18.30  18.43   24923          163  18.356868

[128 rows x 7 columns]
```

help!!

Comment: what did you try? how did it fail?